# NSManagedObject Custom Required Rule?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In my app I have a custom requirement for attributes of my NSManagedObject.

So my entity is `Person` and `Person` has attributes, `firstName` and `lastName`.

Instead of normally just ticking the required tick box in my data model, I need to have just one required. So, if a `firstName` exists, `lastName` isn't required and visa versa.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Josh, did you have a chance to check my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this! Yep I gave it try and it works really well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by implementing `validateForInsert:` and `validateForUpdate:` in your managed object subclass.

This is documented (with an example) in [Inter-Property validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH20-SW1) in the "Core Data Programming Guide".